# Ubuntu 20.04 JMicron PCI-E Sata

Tags: 20.04, sata, pcie

Recently I bought PCI-E card with 5 sata port with chipset JMB585. It does not get detected by the system. When I do `lspci` I get the same output as when the card is not plugged in.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:05.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 61)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Phison Electronics Corporation E12 NVMe Controller (rev 01)
02:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ee
02:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43eb
02:00.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43e9
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ea
03:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ea
03:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ea
03:08.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ea
03:09.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ea
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
29:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
2a:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller (rev 04)
2b:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 710] (rev a1)
2b:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller (rev a1)
2c:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function
2d:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP
2d:00.1 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Cryptographic Coprocessor PSPCPP
2d:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller
2d:00.4 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
```

Here is the output of `lsblk` note that I have 4 HDDs attached directly to the motherboard ports.

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0  55,5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2074
loop1         7:1    0  55,5M  1 loop /snap/core18/1988
loop2         7:2    0  65,1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
loop3         7:3    0    51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/518
loop4         7:4    0  32,3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12159
loop5         7:5    0  64,8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
loop6         7:6    0    51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/547
loop7         7:7    0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
loop8         7:8    0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
loop9         7:9    0  32,3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12398
sda           8:0    0   7,3T  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    0   7,3T  0 part /mnt/hdd1
sdb           8:16   0   7,3T  0 disk 
└─sdb1        8:17   0   7,3T  0 part /mnt/hdd2
sdc           8:32   0   7,3T  0 disk 
└─sdc1        8:33   0   7,3T  0 part /mnt/hdd3
sdd           8:48   0   7,3T  0 disk 
└─sdd1        8:49   0   7,3T  0 part /mnt/hdd4
nvme0n1     259:0    0 953,9G  0 disk /mnt/nvme
nvme1n1     259:1    0 232,9G  0 disk 
├─nvme1n1p1 259:2    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─nvme1n1p2 259:3    0 232,4G  0 part /
```

I have `msi mag b550m mortar wifi` motherboard.

I tried searching for drivers and there are only for Windows but on the manual it says that it supports Linux.
How should I troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Issues was with motherboard limits. I had both M.2 slots used witch blocks another PCI-E x16.